# What to do with unused pins in PCB board of Raspberry Pi 4 Compute Module?

Tags: pcb, raspberry-pi, eaglecad, pins

I'm trying to make a PCB board for Raspberry Pi 4 Compute Module and I will only use power pins, one HDMI connector pins, one USB connector and UART pins (Tx and Rx) only. The rest of the pins will not be used on the PCB. I'm confused about what to do with unused pins?

Comment: What does the manual say how to connect unsed pins?

Comment: I cant find any information. Can you tell me how can I check ?